# clarification on allowable queries in Facebook keyword search

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, keyword

I have tried to find documentation on this and still found nothing. I figured out that facebook graph api allows the OR search but uses the | symbol and even then the results are not 100% accurate. I see it just takes a group of terms and ANDs it together and parenthesis and quotes do not matter. Is there anyway to utilize NOTs or NEGATE searches within the facebook graph api? What other searches (boolean) can be utilized within the facebook graph api?

Answer (score 1):

negation is not supported, says this source: http://civic.mit.edu/blog/mstem/graph-search-rejiggers-your-personal-info